# Is it acceptable to have 100% ownership on every Cassandra node?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am working on a Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes and this is the current ownership rate:

```
19:36:30 root@node01:~# nodetool status foo
Datacenter: Foo
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.190.105  55.69 GB   256     100.0%            aaaaaaaa-7af2-4df8-a2a4-123456789abcd  RAC1
UN  192.168.190.98   82.73 GB   256     100.0%            aaaaaaab-f9d9-4904-aeaa-123456789abcf  RAC1
UN  192.168.190.96   65.43 GB   256     100.0%            aaaaaaac-2d4d-40e0-a9b4-123456789abcg  RAC1
```

Shouldn't it be 33/33/33? I think this way all of the data is on all of the servers and it is not distributed among the nodes. Is this a health state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

33/33/33 will be when number of replica is 1. (100% data divided in 3 nodes).

Based on  your nodetool status you have 3 nodes each having 100% ownership.

This simply states that you have number of replicas set to 3 so effectively copy of same data is available on other 2 nodes as well, hence 100% ownership.